# Is Date X + 365 days and Date X + 1 Year always will result in same date?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, calendar-computations

In particular,

1. Date X + 12 Months
2. Date X + 1 Year
3. Date X + 365 days

Will these result in all same dates at any point of X?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Hint: what was $365$ days after $1$ March $2019$?

Answer (score 2):

It will not, the third example might be different from the other two because of leap years. A leap year have 366 days, so if between date X and date X + 1year there is a leap day, date X + 365 will result in one day less than date X + 1year

Also, it's important to state that this question is not a really good one, as stated by José Carlos Santos in the comments of this answer, and you should improve it, as to make this comunity more organized, and a better place for people who enjoy math and want to learn more.

Comment: This question goes against our [quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I'm sorry. Another person already commented that it was a bad question, so I thought I would just answer his question to help him, as he already had been given guidance.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Osmar thank you, soul kind